# Remote debugging eclipse+pydev with ssh connection to linux server breakpoints are not found

Tags: python, debugging, eclipse-plugin, pydev, remote-debugging

I am struggling on setting up pydev remote debugging feature.
I run Eclipse on my windows laptop and the code is on the linux server.

As far as I've understood the manual http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html I have to have an exact local copy of the code to debug on my laptop and I need to link it with the code on the linux server with PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON variable. However no matter how I set this variable in the pydevd_file_utils.py on the server the paths in the error message don't change.

For each breakpoint I receive:
pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /home/user/D:\Workspace\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\****\home\user\Code\reco\Test2D.py (will have no effect)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoovY.png)

How can I link this particular file, so I can debug it with breakpoints? Is a local copy of the file necessary, even though I can access the original file via windows network drive mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,

I have solved it in a not very intuitive way. For some reason, PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON variable in the pydevd_file_utils.py file didn't change the really used path for the server. I had to manually edit the _norm_file_to_server function in changing the path for the translated variable from _NormFile(translated) to the path of the debugged file e.g "home/user/code.py". After starting debug server I could start the execution of the file with a remote console, e.g python "home/user/code.py"and it worked properly by popping up and stopping at the breakpoint in eclipse.